# Trying to prove and equivalent definition of stochastic processes.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Explicitly I want to show, that a family of mappings $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ with $X_t :\rightarrow S$, $t\in T$ is a stochastic process, iff the mapping $X: \Omega \rightarrow S^T$, wich maps $\omega$ to the path $X(\omega):T\rightarrow S$ with $X(\omega)(t)=X_t(\omega)$, is $\mathcal{A}-S^T$-measurable. My attempt is below, please give advise if necessary. $$$$If the mapping $X$ is $\mathcal{A}-S^T$-measurable,  $(X_t)^{-1}(A)\subset \mathcal{A}$ and thus the family $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ is $\mathcal{A}-S$- measurable and thus a stochastic Process. Now for the other direction: $S^T=\sigma(\cup_{t\in T}\pi^{-1}_t(S_t))$. Where $\pi_i$:$(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n)\rightarrow \omega_i$. Now $X^{-1}(\pi^{-1}_tS_t)=(\pi_t\circ X)^{-1}S_t=X_i^{-1}S_t\subset\mathcal{A}$ by Assumption. This means $X$ is $\mathcal{A}-S^T$-measurable.